# how to install TikZ/ PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, windows

I recently came across a program called TikZ, for creating graphics.
I don't know how to install it! In its website I didn't see any instructions.
Could any one help me?
I am using Windows 7 Home edition.
Thanks

Comment: There is no need to 'install' `TikZ`. Just write `\usepackage{tikz}` in your document. As you are new to it, you should have a look at [A very minimal Introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf).

Comment: Do you have LaTeX installed at all? If not, you will probably need to start with some general introductions to the entire area.

Comment: Well, you should install the surrounding `LaTeX` of course too ;-) Welcome to TeX.SX! anyway!

Comment: To clarify, `tikz` is a package for LaTeX and most TeX distributions contain `tikz` as standard.  MiKTeX is a common distribution to use on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TikZ is not a "program", but a package for LaTeX (and other versions of TeX).
If you just want to create graphics and don't know anything about (La)TeX you should make yourself familiar with that (e.g. by reading [the article about LaTeX on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)).

If you are using LaTeX, you can use TikZ with

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

if it is included in your TeX distribution (which is the case for most distributions).